# Access files from one computer to another using remote extensions

Tags: vscode-remote

I have some code on my own computer but while I'm moving, I'd like to access files on this computer from my laptop
I thought about using vscode remote extensions but I'm having trouble connecting to my pc
I think I should expose my pc to ssh access but can't find any resources on that

Is what I want even possible?

Thanks

Comment: [This guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) walks through setting up the VS Code remote ssh extension. If that doesn't help, please try rephrasing your question to ask about a specific problem or issue that you run into while trying to set up the remote ssh extension

Comment: It doesn't explain how to setup a windows 10 as host, open it for secured remote access and access the code from a local VS code instance

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse